# whilst on a vpn cannot access some urls

Tags: windows-7, networking, vpn

I use windows 7 machine and a VPN to access a remote work computer. This worked fine and I was able to also access skype simultaneously on the home machine (to take a work call with smooth sound) and other internet access.

Today I replaced this PC with a new one (windows 7 professional) and now whilst on the VPN I can no longer access skype (locally) and some secondary URLs that the browser needs to render the web pages have become unavailable such as CDN Jquery files an example below.

http://i2.iis.net/umbraco-beta-scripts/jquery-1.8.2.min.js?cdn_id=2012-08-15-001

Windows Defender appears to be enabled. Windows firewall says its on for public networks, not home and Norton appears to be controlling some of this on this HP Pro machine, but it says it wants to turn firewall on. All OK as I say when off the VPN and on the old machine with VPN connected.

Why would that happen now and not before, and what can I do to make it work nicely again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try going to the properties of your Windows VPN, clicking the Networking tab, selecting Internet Protocol Version 4 and then clicking Properties. Click Advanced and if the 'Use default gateway on remote network' is checked, try unchecking it. Red-dial the VPN and see if that fixes the issue.

Comment: yes thanks that worked, and the redial vpn was necessary